# Use the id from a button to fill out a form PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am completely fresh to any Javascript, AJAX or jQuery so I'm struggling to understand the detailed concepts people have proposed on other questions.

I have a script that shows all the users within a database in a table. This table also includes a button that has an ID depending on its primary key. **I can't figure out how to when it is pressed to select all of its records and place it into the form which is directly below it when the button is pressed.**
(admin.php).

I attempted to use a piece of AJAX code to show and hide it with the hope that I could reach the ID but my last post was difficult to explain and gave a variety of answers that were not related to the solution I was looking for.

*admin.php*

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Append User</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="#">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="accesslevel">Access Level</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select>
                        <option value="0">No Admin Access</option>
                        <option value="1">Admin Access</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="securityanswer">Security Answer</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="securityanswer" name="securityanswer" placeholder="Security Answer"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="append" value="Append">Append</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

*accessusers.php*

```
    echo "<table class='table text-center'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Access Level</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Security Answer</th>
    <th>Date Joined</th>
    <th>Edit Row</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['usersid'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['accesslevel'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['securityanswer'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a id='" . $row['userid'] . "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - what is the relation between the two scripts above? Does the form on `admin.php` POST it's data to `accessusers.php`? There is no javascript code shown in the question yet you refer to javascript / jQuery code. The HTML code in `accessusers.php` has no buttons, only some data and a hyperlink to each specific user

Comment: @RamRaider the html has a form and a submit button, so yes there is a relation. He has issues understanding and implementing Ajax.

Comment: @RamRaider The accessuser.php outputs the table to the admin.php page which include. This is just before the form shown as admin.php. This is the testing version but <a> is now <button>.

Comment: @Xorifelse - the form does not POST directly to `accessusers.php` as th action is `#` so if it does POST to that script it must be done with javascript which is not shown.

Comment: @ParagonJenko - you will need to use javascript to set the various form values based upon which hyperlink / button you press - using the `userid` as the parameter you pass to whatever php script it is that process the request

Comment: @RamRaider I realized that, as I did not discard your comment. I suspected that this was working html & php code, trying to implement ajax which is for you and me both, completely missing. So.. Paragon that leaves you to read a little on jQuery post requests and modify your PHP to return a json response and lastly convert your json response to insert into your html. Because well, I am *not* writing that from scrap. Give us  your hard word so we can C&P and edit a few lines of code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you wish to set the values, in the form, based upon the table cell values displayed in `accessusers.php` when a button is clicked? If so the following might be useful - it's roughly tested but there may be issues. One thing to note is that the `SELECT` element in the form does not have a `name` attribute - I assumed it should be called `accesslevel` - ie: `<select name='accesslevel'>...</select>`

```
<script>
    /*
        Event handler assigned to each button in the table found within `accessusers.php`
    */
    function setvalues(e){
        /*
            column names / form fields - not all get populated such a userid
        */
        var columns=['usersid','accesslevel','username','password','email','securityanswer','date'];
        var tr=this.parentNode.parentNode;
        var col=tr.querySelectorAll('td');
        var form=document.getElementById('loginForm');

        /* iterate through all table cells found on this row */
        for( var n in col ){
            if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ) {
                /* 
                    if there is a form element in `admin.php` with this name, 
                    add the value from the table cell that corresponds
                */

                if( typeof( columns[ n ] )!='undefined' ){
                    if( typeof( form[ columns[ n ] ] ) == 'object' ){
                        var field=form[ columns[ n ] ];

                        if( field.tagName=='SELECT' ) field.selectedIndex=col[ n ].innerHTML;
                        else field.value=col[ n ].innerHTML;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    Assign event handlers to the buttons
    */
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(evt){
        var table=document.querySelectorAll('table[class="table text-center"]')[0];
        /*
            below assumes the hyperlinks have been replaced with buttons
        */
        var bttns=table.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
        if( bttns ){
            for( var b in bttns ){
                var bttn=bttns[ b ];
                if( bttn.nodeType==1 )bttn.onclick=setvalues.bind( bttn );
            }
        }
    },false);
</script>
```